# Google colab - is there a way to record peak RAM during session?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ram

The bar on the top right isn't very precise and I can't just watch it all day.

Is there a precise way to estimate how much RAM is peaking at during a machine learning process?

Answer (score 0):

we can use any Linux commands in google colab.
We can use any cmd command with add prefix '!'.

For example,

```sh
!ls
```

Your best bet is to either create a bash script that will run in the background and will save memory usage or use some of Linux system tools.

Another [StackOverflow thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332004/how-can-i-see-memory-usage-history), which will be useful for you.